# About HTML tags in Struts 2 framework

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsp, struts2

I want to know if it's actually possible, and allowed to use html tags, to set values in the action class via `name` attribute using Struts2 framework, for example:

Human bean:

```
String name;
```

Action class has this line:

```
Human human;
```

Form:

```
<s:textfield name="human.name"/>
```

but in this case, would be:

```
<input type="text" name="human.name"/>
```

In this particular case, it is required to use the input html tag, cause part of the form is being generated dynamically and repeatedly using jQuery, and it seems to have issues generating Struts tags, the first time the page loads, it actually doesn't load, it redirects to some made `error.jsp`, when you refresh the page, then it works, which doesn't happen when I generate the standard html tag, shouldn't be like that, we're not testing code yet, first the user interface, so I need to know this. Is it possible or allowed to do that? and if it is, Would the performance or quality be affected?

Answer (score 0):

Struts and any other JSP tags used to generate HTML on the server. In any case, you could see the HTML source code generated by framework in the browser.

Use the `name` attribute of the `input` elements to map to the action properties.

Struts tags are processed on the server, while javascript is executed on the client, so it should not affect the server performance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, then it'll be fine (: